# Sorting an arrayList based on a specific value in it with grouping

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

My code is as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Sorting {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<String> theMenu = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] Array1 = {
             "M1", "Wine",        "2.50",
              "M2", "Soft drink",  "1.50",
             "D1", "Fish",        "7.95",
             "D2", "Veg chili",   "6.70"
    };
    theMenu.addAll(Arrays.asList(Array1));

    String[] temp1 = new String[3];
    String[] temp2 = new String[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < theMenu.size(); i+=3) {
        for (int j = i + 3; j < theMenu.size(); j+=3) {
        if (i < theMenu.size() - 3) {
        if (theMenu.get(i).compareTo(theMenu.get(i + 3)) > 0) {


            temp1[0] = theMenu.get(i);
            temp1[1] = theMenu.get(i + 1);
            temp1[2] = theMenu.get(i + 2);

            temp2[0] = theMenu.get(j);
            temp2[1] = theMenu.get(j+1);
            temp2[2] = theMenu.get(j+2);

            theMenu.remove(j  + 2);
            theMenu.remove(j + 1);
            theMenu.remove(j);
            theMenu.remove(i + 2);
            theMenu.remove(i + 1);
            theMenu.remove(i);

            theMenu.add(i, temp2[0]);
            theMenu.add(i + 1, temp2[1]);
            theMenu.add(i + 2, temp2[2]);

            theMenu.add(j, temp1[0]);
            theMenu.add(j + 1, temp1[1]);
            theMenu.add(j + 2, temp1[2]);


        }
        }

        }

    }

    System.out.println(theMenu);

}
```

}

I want to sort the ArrayList in the order D1, D2, M1, M2, M3, while keeping its respective items and price WITH the IDs. I am not allowed to change the storing method i.e make another class of Items with its own ID and name and price. How can I rearrange it so that it is in the form :

```
{"D1" , "Fish", "7.95"
 "D2" , "Veg chili", "6.70",
 "M1" , "Wine", "2.50",
 "M2", "Soft drink", "1.50"
 }
```

Inside the ArrayList. This should work regardless of how many items we store inn the arrayList. My code produces the following output:

```
[M1, Wine, 2.50, M2, Soft drink, 1.50, D1, Fish, 7.95, D2, Veg chili, 6.70]
```

Note: Forget the new lines in the array, I just need the indexes sorted out. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: The problem statement is so weird that it's either homework or an interview question. Still, it shouldn't be that hard to select your favorite sorting algorithm and just treat the arraylist in triplets.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, you have a entity - product, which has Id, name and price. 
Always create new class for each Entity in your application. 
Example:

```
public class MyObject implements Comparable
{
  private String id;
  private String name;
  private double price;

  public MyObject(String id, String name, double price)
  {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
  }

  public String getId()
  {
    return id;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Object o)
  {
    MyObject receivedObject = (MyObject) o;
    return this.id.compareTo(receivedObject.getId());
  }

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return "MyObject{" +
        "id='" + id + '\'' +
        ", name='" + name + '\'' +
        ", price=" + price +
        '}';
  }
}
```

I use "implements Comparable" for easy write sorting. When we implement this interphace we must override

```
public int compareTo(Object o)
{
  MyObject receivedObject = (MyObject) o;
  return this.id.compareTo(receivedObject.getId());
}
```

This method compare 2 Objects and say which object "bigger". In your case we need compare only by Ids.

Now you have entity with ability to compare with each other. Check it:

```
public class Processing
{
  public static void main(String[] argc) {
    List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new MyObject("M1", "Wine", 2.50));
    list.add(new MyObject("M2", "Soft drink", 1.50));
    list.add(new MyObject("D1", "Fish", 7.95));
    list.add(new MyObject("D2", "Veg chili", 6.70));

    System.out.println(list);

    Collections.sort(list);
    System.out.println(list);
  }
}
```

First output:

```
MyObject{id='M1', name='Wine', price=2.5},
MyObject{id='M2', name='Soft drink', price=1.5},
MyObject{id='D1', name='Fish', price=7.95},
MyObject{id='D2', name='Veg chili', price=6.7}
```

Second output:

```
MyObject{id='D1', name='Fish', price=7.95},
MyObject{id='D2', name='Veg chili', price=6.7},
MyObject{id='M1', name='Wine', price=2.5},
MyObject{id='M2', name='Soft drink', price=1.5}
```

Comment: He said he can't make a class to contain the info.